# Converting an input text value to a decimal number

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to work with decimal data in my `PHP` and `MySql` practice and I'm not sure about how can I do for an acceptable level af accuracy.

I've wrote a simple `function` which recives my `input text value` and converts it to a `decimal number` ready to be stored in the database.

```
<?php

function unit ($value, $decimal_point = 2) {
    return number_format (str_replace (",", ".", strip_tags (trim ($value))), $decimal_point);
}

?>
```

I've resolved something like `AbdlBsF5%?nl` with some jQuery code for replace and some regex to keep only numbers, dots and commas.

In some country, people uses the comma `,` to send decimal numbers, so a number like `72.08` is wrote like `72,08`. I'd like avoid to forcing people to change their usual chars and I've decided to use a jQuery to keep this too.

Now every web developer knows the last validation must be handled by the dynamic page for security reasons.

So my answer is should I use something like `unit ();` function to store data or should I also check if users inserts invalid chars like letters or something else? If I try this and send letters, the query works without save the invalid data, I think this isn't bad, but I could easily be wrong because I'm a rookie.

What kind of method should I use for my query if I want a number like `99999.99`?

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to consider formatting also  [DATABASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) values with something like `FLOAT(10,2)`

IMHO this is also very important!

then, of course use server side language for make real validation is the best practice!

you can read this:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

javascript can be fancy and handy but not secure although!

Comment: Thanks for remind, I've opted for decimal after a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828068/best-mysql-datatype-for-grams-milligrams-micrograms-and-kilojoule here